# Draw custom panel with control in wx.VListBox OnDrawItem()

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a simple app that shows a list of user infos in wx.VListBox
Each item is rendered using OnDrawItem() and everything works fine when I need to draw a text, a line or an image.

The app look:

[image]

How to add beside few text labels (name and email) also few wx.ComboBox, few wx.ComboBox to each row?

I see solution as rendering some custom control based on wx.Panel that has all controls laid out on that panel but how to render a panel with it's child controls on each row of wx.VListBox?

My current complete code (just copy/paste):

```
import wx


class UserInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, email, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.name = name
        self.email = email


class UserListBox(wx.VListBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, users, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bh = 10
        self.users = users

        self.SetItemCount(len(self.users))

    def OnMeasureItem(self, idx):
        image_height = self.bh + 4
        name_size = self.GetTextExtent(self.users[idx].name)
        email_size = self.GetTextExtent(self.users[idx].email)
        return max(image_height, name_size[1] + email_size[1] + 6)

    def OnDrawSeparator(self, dc, rect, idx):
        oldpen = dc.GetPen()
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK))
        dc.DrawLine(rect.x, rect.y, rect.x + rect.width, rect.y)
        rect.Deflate(0, 2)
        dc.SetPen(oldpen)

    def OnDrawItem(self, dc, rect, n):
        # Draw the name label to the right of the bitmap
        textx = rect.x + 2 + self.bh + 2
        lblrect = wx.Rect(textx, rect.y,
                          rect.width - textx,
                          rect.height)
        user = self.users[n]
        dc.DrawLabel(user.name, lblrect,
                     wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        dc.DrawLabel(user.email, lblrect,
                     wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)


class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        users = list()
        for n in range(100):
            users.append(UserInfo('John %s' % n, 'john@doe.com'))

        listobx = UserListBox(self, users, size=(150, 250), style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        sizer.Add(listobx, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Do it!')
        sizer.Add(btn)


class DemoApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = AppFrame(None, title="App Demo")
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = DemoApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods of [wxRendererNative](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_renderer_native.html) class to draw natively-looking representations of custom controls, e.g. in your case you'd use `DrawComboBoxDropButton()`. You will have to create a real `wxComboBox` whenever the image is clicked (or maybe even when the mouse just hovers over it) to allow the user to change its value.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But how to track click/hover that particular image over whole listbox cell? And even more interesting - how in-place that image with real control on the same coordinates and remove the control again. Can you suggest any place with a code sample?

Comment: You can bind to the mouse move event and use `VirtualHitTest()` to get the item under it, but finding the exact location of the combo button risks being tricky, if you can just overlap the cell entirely with the real combobox, it would be the simplest solution. Removing the control is simple: just do it when it loses focus.